Countdown works only on active browser tab
I have a JavaScript function that I'm using in Oracle APEX, which assigns a countdown timer to an item on the page, counting down from 5 minutes to 0. When the value reaches 0, the user gets a modal prompt asking if they're still on the page. The countdown works correctly, but only when the specific tab is open in the browser. When I have multiple tabs open, the countdown pauses and resumes only when I switch back to the tab with my application. I'd like this timer to run independently of whether the tab is open or not.
var timeoutHandle;
function countdown(minutes) {
    var seconds = 0;
    var mins = minutes;
    function tick() {
        var current_minutes = mins;
        var current_seconds = seconds;
        
        if (current_seconds === 0 && current_minutes === 0) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
            return;
        }
        
        if (current_seconds === 0) {
            current_minutes--;
            current_seconds = 59;
        } else {
            current_seconds--;
        }
        
        var c = current_minutes.toString() + ":"
            + (current_seconds < 10 ? "0" : "")
            + current_seconds.toString();
        
        apex.item('P0_SESSION_TIMER').setValue(c);
        timeoutHandle = setTimeout(tick, 1000);
        
        seconds = current_seconds;
        mins = current_minutes;
    }
    tick();
}


Any suggestions on how to make the timer function independently of browser tabs would be greatly appreciated.

Perhaps instead of explicitly counting down, the timer just compares the current time with a known point in time and observes the result of that comparison?  That way even if it's paused and resumed the calculation doesn't change.

Can you use Local Storage in Oracle Apex?

Yes, I can use Local Storage, but I'm looking for the easiest way to achieve this. Is there any way to tweak my code so that it works properly? I don't have much experience with JavaScript.
